# Two synchronized lists how to delete element in both lists

Tags: delete, item

I have got two lists with unical name.

I have got, this code:

```
        public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemDeleting(properties);
        if (properties.List.Title == "Jawna")
        {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(properties.Web.ID))
                        {
                            SPList list = web.Lists["Niejawna"];
                            SPListItem itemToDelete = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
                            itemToDelete.Delete();

                        }
                    }
                });
        }
        else if (properties.List.Title == "Niejawna")
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(properties.Web.ID))
                    {


                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

How to get list item ID by give, a name of unical field. By Caml or Linq. Could you give a sample of code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check my code below. You need to add the name of the column which contains the information from which you can identify the item. The ID column doesn't work, because it could easily get out of sync.

```
public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    string otherListtitle;
    if (properties.List.Title == "Jawna")
       otherListtitle = "Niejawna";
    else
       otherListtitle = "Jawna";

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(properties.Web.ID))
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(otherListtitle);
                var query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='YOURCOLUMN' /><Value Type='Text'>YOURVALUE</Value></Eq></Where>";

                var itemToDelete = list.GetItems(query).Cast<SPListItem>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (itemToDelete != null)
                {   
                    itemToDelete.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    base.ItemDeleting(properties);
}
```

Comment: I have got this error: Error 1 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) \Dodawanie_Updatowanie_Elementu.cs 114 65 AddElementListUpdate

Comment: Please make sure you got "using System.Linq;" in your code.

Comment: And how tu use, haw to learn Linq to Sharepoint. Have You know any tutorial site to Linq with Sharepoint ?

Comment: I get a error, that item don't exist.

Comment: But it deleting element in both list, but i don't know why I getting this error

Comment: So you changed the name of the column (please be aware that there's a difference between field title and internal field name) and the value? Regarding Linq I find this [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) very useful.

Comment: I know Why it's throw a Error. It's because we forgot abaut:
this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
:)